# Serialising file transfers on iOS Phonegap application

Tags: ios, cordova, serialization, file-transfer

I have an phonegap app for iOS that downloads the images and pdf files from the server as they have to be available locally.

I parse using jQuery to find a list of assets I need to download and then initiate the FileTransfer using the Phonegap API as follows:

```
// assets is an array that has all pdf and image urls to be downloaded.
assets.map(downloadFile);

function downloadFile(file_url){
    console.log('Downloading file:'+file_url);
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

    fileTransfer.download(
        file_url,
        get_local_file_path(file_url),
        download_success,
        function(error) {
            stopspin();
            console.log('ERROR downloading: '+ error.source);
            $('#notify-user').html('Downloading failed. <a href="#" onclick="checkLatestIssue()">Try again?</a>')
        }
    );
}
```

Now, the assets can be upto 50 of them each time. I can see that all the filetransfer requests are sent immediately and sometimes, some of the file transfer requests time out, thus making the download incomplete for me to render via local assets.

Is there a way I can make this downloading of all these issues serial with about 5 parallel downloads?

Answer (score 2):

What I do on my application is create a global array of files I need to download and then initiate code that grabs the first element off the front of the array and downloads it. When it's done it checks to see if there is another item to process in the array, if so it starts the process over again. If not, it finalizes the download and continues on with whatever the application needs to do next.

create a blank array for our files to download
`data_to_process = [];`

add images and video to the array form "result" which was returned from an API

```
// add images to array
$.each( result.images_to_download, function( index, value ) {

    index = index + 1;
    data_to_process.push(
        {
            "type":     "images",
            "filename": value,
            "msg":      "Downloading image "+index+" of "+result.images_to_download.length+"..."
        }
    );
});

// add videos to array
$.each( result.videos_to_download, function( index, value ) {

index = index + 1;
data_to_process.push(
    {
        "type":     "videos",
        "filename": value,
        "msg":      "Downloading video "+index+" of "+result.videos_to_download.length+"..."
    }
);
});
```

here's the code that processes the files
Note: there is some unneeded code in here that I use to put files in certain directories based on what it is, update a percentage indicator of download progress, etc:

```
// values for percentages
start_data_length = data_to_process.length;
current_iteration = 0;

// set writing to false
writing = false;

// what we do after each iteration in the data array
var finish_processing = function() {

    // increment iteration count
    current_iteration++;

    // set percent value
    var percent = current_iteration / start_data_length * 100;
    percent = Math.round( percent );
    $('#update_percent').html( percent );

    // remove from array after process
    data_to_process.splice( 0, 1 );

    // set writing back to false so we can start another iteration
    writing = false;
}

// checks if we need to process the next part of the array or not
var check_to_process = function() {

    // console.log('checking if we need to process');

    // if we still have items in the array to process
    if ( data_to_process.length > 0 ) {

        // if we're currently not working on an item
        if ( writing === false ) {

            // process next item in array
            process_download_data();

        } else {

            // not ready yet, wait .5 seconds and check again
            // console.log('busy - waiting to process');
            setTimeout( check_to_process, 500 );
        }

    } else {

        // console.log('nothing left to process');
    }
}

// processes the downloaded data
var process_download_data = function() {

    // set writing to true
    writing = true;

    // current item to process is first item in array
    var current_item = data_to_process[0];

    if ( current_item.msg ) {
        $('#update_item').html(current_item.msg);
    } else {
        $('#update_item').html('Processing update data...');
    }
    // console.log( 'processing this: '+ current_item.filename );

    // if something didn't work right..
    var broke = function(error) {

        // console.log( 'error' );
        // console.log( error );

        // cycle to next item in array
        finish_processing();
    }

    // get the directory of current item's "type"
    var get_directory = function( fileSystem ) { 
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory( current_item.type, {create:true,exclusive:false}, get_file, broke ); 
    } 

    // get the file
    var get_file = function( dirEntry ){

        // if texts
        if ( current_item.type == 'texts' ) {

            dirEntry.getFile( current_item.filename+".txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, create_text_writer, broke); 

        // if images
        } else if ( current_item.type == 'images' ) {

            var localFileName = current_item.filename.substring(current_item.filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

            dirEntry.getFile( localFileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, create_file_writer, broke);

        // if videos
        } else if ( current_item.type == 'videos' ) {

            var localFileName = current_item.filename.substring(current_item.filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

            dirEntry.getFile( localFileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, create_file_writer, broke);

        // if audios
        } else if ( current_item.type == 'resources' ) {

            var localFileName = current_item.filename.substring(current_item.filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

            dirEntry.getFile( localFileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, create_file_writer, broke);

        // if audios
        } else if ( current_item.type == 'audios' ) {

            var localFileName = current_item.filename.substring(current_item.filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

            dirEntry.getFile( localFileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, create_file_writer, broke);
        }
    } 

    // write to file using filetransfer
    var create_file_writer = function( fileEntry ) {

        if ( current_item.remove === true ) {

            fileEntry.remove( function(entry) {

                // what to do when image is deleted
                finish_processing();

            },broke);

        } else {

            var localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;

            // console.log('Writing to: '+localPath+' from: '+current_item.filename);

            var ft = new FileTransfer();

            ft.download( current_item.filename, localPath, function(entry) {

                // what to do when image is downloaded
                finish_processing();

            },broke);
        }
    }

    // create writer for "texts" type
    var create_text_writer = function( fileEntry ) { 
        fileEntry.createWriter( write_text_file, broke ); 
    } 

    // write to file for "texts" type
    var write_text_file = function( writer ) {

        // write new contents
        writer.write( current_item.data );

        // add item where it needs to be in the document
        if ( current_item.append === true ) {

            $('#'+current_item.marker).nextAll().remove();

            // appending
            // console.log('Appending data to: #'+current_item.id);
            $('#'+current_item.id).append( current_item.data );

        } else {

            // adding
            // console.log('Adding data to: #'+current_item.id);
            $('#'+current_item.id).html( current_item.data );
        }

        // console.log('finished writing: '+current_item.filename);

        finish_processing();
    }

    // request persistent filesystem
    window.requestFileSystem( LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, get_directory, broke );

    // check if we need to process the next item yet
    check_to_process();
}

// process data from the update
process_download_data();
```